# could not find a part of the path c# when save file Linux server to windows server

Tags: c#, linux, file, server, save

My services codes are on `Linux` server. I am getting this error:

```
'could not find a part of the path'
```

when trying to save a file on Linux server to `Windows` server. But I can save a file from Windows server to Windows server similar path.

```
    string path = "";
            int lastIndexOfSlash = file.FilePath.LastIndexOf('/');
            if (lastIndexOfSlash != -1)
            {
                path = file.FilePath.Substring(0, lastIndexOfSlash);
            }

            Directory.CreateDirectory(fileSystemBaseAddress + "\\" + path);
            string lastPath = Path.Combine(fileSystemBaseAddress, file.FilePath);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(lastPath, file.FileContent);
```

Comment: Normally when you ask a question you would show the code that causes the error. But even without seeing it I'm going to guess that you are not using `Path.Combine()` to build the path to the file. That is a big help, especially for portability.

Comment: Hi i am new to stackoverflow, i didn't know to format, sorry. İ update my ask, adding code